# Common body, different return type

Tags: c#

I have two methods that take the same parameters, the body of the methods are the same except the client call, the client returns a different object. If I want to combine these methods, is boxing/unboxing the only option by returning a generic object? What is the best practice for this?

```
IRestResponse SyncRestRequest(string url, string method, string data) { some code... client.Execute(request); }

Task<IRestResponse> AsyncRestRequest(string url, string method, string data) { some code... client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request); }
```

Comment: You have sync and async versions of the same method, it isn't a good idea to combine them. Or you can just leave an async version

Comment: Is `AsyncRestRequest` asynchronous? Should it be `async Task<IRestResponse>`?

Answer (score 2):

I read the question three times and I'm still confused... I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

So... you can't have methods with the same signature (same name, same parameters) and different return types.

If you want to have different return types that means you have different semantics... so different methods.

You can, however, have different names for the two methods, like you did in your example.

If you have some common logic, used in both methods, the best practice is to **extract that logic in a private method** which is used/called by both these methods:

```
Result SyncMethod(){ CommonLogic(); return new Result(); }
Task<Result> AsyncMethod(){ CommonLogic(); return AsyncResultProcessor(); }
private void CommonLogic(){ some code ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could parameterize the part that differs, like this:

```
R RestRequest<R>(string url, string method, string data, Func<Client, Request, R> executor) 
{
    // some code...
    return executor(client, request);
}
```

...used like:

```
Foo.RestRequest(url, method, data, (client, request) => client.Execute(request));

// or

Foo.RestRequest(url, method, data, (client, request) => client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request));
```

Comment: Does this allow awaiting the async version?

Comment: No man... this looks so nasty... :(  Pretty far away from "best practice"... and it doesn't resolve the problem since you have the same return type.

Comment: @Hintee: false. It's returning type `R`, which is generic. It'll return whatever type the delegate returns.

Comment: You're correct, sorry, I missed that. But still... I personally don't consider this approach a best practice... I would do it this way if I had no other option... say a legacy system, or something similar.

Comment: @ScottHannen if `executor` returns a `Task<>`, it should be awaitable.

Comment: This wouldn't work for an async delegate, you can't await `R`

Comment: If `R` is a `Task<>`, yes you can. Type inference.